# retrieving result from php file to swift in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, swift

I am having trouble getting data from a php file.
I'm making an health and fitness type app like myfitnesspal. 
I'm having trouble getting a to output the reuslt of a query in a php file and print the result in swift.

here is the php (getDetails.php)

```
<?php

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");
$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);

$returnValue = array();


$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

$returnValue["user"] =  $userDetails;

echo json_encode($returnValue);


$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

MySQLDao.php

```
public function getUserDetails($email)
{ 
$returnValue = array();
$test = array();
$sql = "select calories from users where username='" . $email . "'"; 

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$returnValue = $row;

if (!empty($row)) {
}
}
return $returnValue;
}
```

finally my swift code

```
   let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/getDetails.php");
         let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!);
       request.HTTPMethod = "POST";


   let postString = "email=\(userEmail)";

   request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        do{

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json{
                let resultValue = parseJSON["user"] as! String!;
                print("results:\(resultValue)")





            }

        }
        catch {print(error)}

    }

    task.resume();
```

Comment: You need to fetch the result. You also are open to SQL injections, `htmlentities` does nothing to stop injections.

Comment: Can you help me with this. I'm not familiar with php

Comment: I misread, you are fetching. If you `die` and output `$returnValue` what do you get?

Comment: I'm trying to get the output in swift but I can't. I must be missing something simple